# Cordova - How to get a tile title on Windows mobile

Tags: cordova, windows-mobile

I am creating a cordova app from my html/js-code with this cordova-config:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="myapp" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>My App</name>
    <description>
        A small demo app
    </description>
    <author email="dont@ask.me" href="http://anyth.ing">
        My App
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="3.2.0"/>
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true"/>
    <platform name="windows">
        <!-- splashs and icons -->

    </platform>
</widget>
```

But when I deploy the app to my mobile devide (Windows 10 mobile) the tile on the start screen does not show a title. The app itself in the app list has a title but not the tile.

How do I get a tile title in the startscreen tile?

Regards

Tenoda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, Cordova does not provide a preference for adding the Windows tile title. You would assume that Cordova would just take the name present in the *name* element in the config.xml and use it for the home screen tiles.

In order to get a title in the startscreen tile, you will need to edit the package.windows10.appxmanifest located under the platform/windows directory.

Adding the following under the **uap:DefaultTile** element made it work for me:

```
<uap:ShowNameOnTiles>
  <uap:ShowOn Tile="square310x310Logo" />
  <uap:ShowOn Tile="square150x150Logo" />
  <uap:ShowOn Tile="wide310x150Logo" />
</uap:DefaultTile>
```

**Also**: Add the desired title in the **ShortName** attribute for the element **uap:DefaultTile**.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Evertson's answer:

To avoid having to keep editing the platform/windows file, you can copy package.windows10.appxmanifest to the res/native/windows folder. The code should look like this:

```
<uap:DefaultTile ShortName="..." Square310x310Logo="..." etc.>
    <uap:ShowNameOnTiles>
        <uap:ShowOn Tile="square310x310Logo" />
        <uap:ShowOn Tile="square150x150Logo" />
        <uap:ShowOn Tile="wide310x150Logo" />
    </uap:ShowNameOnTiles>
</uap:DefaultTile>
```

Of course, this means you need to edit the manifest any time you make config changes.

Interestingly, the old Windows 8.1 manifest (package.windows.appxmanifest) and Windows 8.1 phone manifest (package.phone.appxmanifestfile) do already include this information by default. No idea why this was removed for windows 10.

**Edit**

You can create a hook to insert the XML so you don't have to worry about applying changes to config.xml:

Add the following: hooks/showNameOnTiles.js

```
module.exports = function (context) {
    "use strict";
    var fs = require('fs'),
        path = context.opts.projectRoot + '/platforms/windows/package.windows10.appxmanifest',
        manifest = fs.readFileSync(path).toString(),
        lines, i, lineNo;
    if (!manifest.includes('uap:ShowNameOnTiles')) {
        lines = manifest.split(/\r?\n/);
        for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            if (lines[i].indexOf('uap:DefaultTile') !== -1) {
                lineNo = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (lineNo) {
            lines[lineNo] = lines[lineNo].replace('/>', '>').replace(' >', '>');
            lines.splice(lineNo + 1, 0, [
                '<uap:ShowNameOnTiles>',
                    '<uap:ShowOn Tile="square310x310Logo" />',
                    '<uap:ShowOn Tile="square150x150Logo" />',
                    '<uap:ShowOn Tile="wide310x150Logo" />',
                '</uap:ShowNameOnTiles>'
            ].join('\n'));
            lines.splice(lineNo + 2, 0, '</uap:DefaultTile>');
            fs.writeFileSync(path, lines.join('\n'));
        }
    }
};
```

In config.xml, add:

```
<platform name="windows">
    <hook type="after_prepare" src="hooks/showNameOnTiles.js" />
</platform>
```

**A simpler way**

There is a simpler way to do this but I couldn't get it to work; you can create your own plugin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" 
    id="com.blah.addtiletitleplugin" version="1.0.0">
  <name>Adds the title to windows 10 tiles</name>
  <description>Adds the title to windows 10 tiles</description>
  <platform name="windows">
    <config-file target="package.windows10.appxmanifest" parent="/Package/Applications/Application/uap:VisualElements/uap:DefaultTile/">
      <uap:ShowNameOnTiles>
        <uap:ShowOn Tile="square310x310Logo" />
        <uap:ShowOn Tile="square150x150Logo" />
        <uap:ShowOn Tile="wide310x150Logo" />
      </uap:ShowNameOnTiles>
    </config-file>
  </platform>
</plugin>
```

However, when I try and add the plugin, visual studio refuses to parse it even though I've specified:

```
xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
```

If I remove the **uap:** parts, it parses and adds but, of course, fails on build.

Comment: I ran into the same Visual Studio parsing problem with the plugin approach. I was able to get it work by 1) commenting out the `<config-file>` block, 2) installing the plugin, 3) un-commenting the `<config-file>` block, 4) removing and re-installing the plugin. The trick was to keep the Plugins/Custom tab displayed during the entire process. I also had to delete the platforms/windows folder and rebuild the app.